Excel VBA transpose/filter to other sheet
I'm trying to automate the sets of data. So far I have this code that filters the data to another sheet but I cannot figure out how to transpose the data vertically. I've tried adding Transpose:=True but it isn't doing anything.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 

Application.CutCopyMode = False 
Sheets("INFO").Range("A1:X246").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _ 
CriteriaRange:=Range("B2:B3"), CopyToRange:=Range("B5:Y5"), Unique:=False 
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=0 
Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit 
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit 

End Sub

Appreciate any help. Thanks.
Tried searching but all comes to a dead end, newbie trying to figure things out.

There's no Transpose option when using AdvancedFilter
